# handle click event of marker for openlayers mobile

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, openlayers

i have integrate openlayer map for my sencha touch application.
and, add marker on particular place.
i am able to handle click event of markers, but as soon as i add  `OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()` marker click event not worked in mobile but it worked in my browser.

i want both navigation of my map and handle click event of marker for mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **touchstart** event as below instead of click event,

```
mark.events.register( 'touchstart', placeMarker, clickMarker );

function clickMarker() {
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("chicken",
                                 new OpenLayers.LonLat(long,lat),
                                 new OpenLayers.Size(120,50),
                                 add,
                                 true);

    map.addPopup(popup);
}
```

This will work in mobile only on marker tap event, not works in browser.
Maybe this will help you.